# how to get session cookie from server response to send back

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

ive been tryint to get my application to authenticate and start a session with another spring boot appilcation, ive been doing it like so.

```
WebClient webClient= WebClient.builder().build();
    String reet=webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:8081/authenticate")
    .header("x-api-key","123456789")
    .header("Connection","keep-alive")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();


query.put("collection","student");
String ret =webClient.post().uri("http://localhost:8081/query")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(query))
    .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

The first request should use the API key and authenticate, which starts the session .
the second one should do a query , which will work IF the user is authenticated.

how do i get the session cookie from the response so i can send it back in the second request ?

Answer (score 0):

This has troubled me a lot and I was not able to retrieve the exact session cookie from webClient due to `ClientResponse` not being able to support `text/html` content-type in my case. So I just parsed the cookie value and created the cookie again and added it in `RestController`.

```java
/**
 * This method call the grafana API to retrieve session cookie value and return it as String
 * 
 * @param userEmail
 * @param grafanaHostname
 * @return String
 */
private String retreiveGrafanaSessionCookieVal(String userEmail, String grafanaHostname) {

    String grafana_url = grafanaHostname + ArgoCDURLConstant.GRAFANA_LOGIN_URL;
    WebClient client1 = WebClient.create(grafana_url);
    String cookieVal = client1.get().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 
        MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
        .header(ArgoCDURLConstant.GRAFANA_WEBAUTH_USER_HEADER, userEmail).accept(MediaType.ALL)
        .exchangeToMono(response -> {
            MultiValueMap<String, ResponseCookie> cookies = response.cookies();
            String grCookieVal = "";
            for (var cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
                //System.out.println(cookie.getKey() + " : " + cookie.getValue());
                List<ResponseCookie> resCookie = cookie.getValue();
                for (ResponseCookie responseCookie : resCookie) {
                    //System.out.println(responseCookie.getName());
                    //System.out.println(grCookieVal = responseCookie.getValue());
                    grCookieVal = responseCookie.getValue();
                }
            }
            return Mono.just(grCookieVal);
        }).block();
    //System.out.println("cookieVal::" + cookieVal);
        
    return cookieVal;
}

/**
 * This method call the grafana API to retrieve session cookie value and set it in
 * cookie
 * 
 * @param userEmail
 * @param domain
 * @param grafanaHostname
 * @return ResponseCookie
 */
public ResponseCookie getGrafanaSessionCookie(String userEmail, String domain, String grafanaHostname) {

    ResponseCookie grafana_cookie;

    String hostname = CommonConstants.DOT + domain.split(CommonConstants.COLON)[0];
    String cookieValue = retreiveGrafanaSessionCookieVal(userEmail, grafanaHostname);

    grafana_cookie = ResponseCookie.from(ArgoCDURLConstant.GRAFANA_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, 
        cookieValue.toString())
        .httpOnly(true).secure(true).domain(hostname)
        // .path("/") // path
        .maxAge(Duration.ofDays(30))
        .sameSite(CommonConstants.COOKIE_SAMESITE_NONE).build();
        
    return grafana_cookie;

}

/* Rest Controller method returning cookie in response. */
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> getGrafanaSession(@RequestHeader(name = "Authorization") String token,
    @RequestParam(value = "hostname", required = false) String grafanaHost, 
    HttpServletResponse response,
    @RequestHeader("Host") String hostname) {

    ResponseCookie grafana_cookie = grafanaService.getGrafanaSessionCookie(grafanaHost, hostname, token,
        grafanaHost);

    // Set cookie in the response
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, grafana_cookie.toString());
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```